# Unable to link rich:panel scroll bar to rich:tree

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Using: JSF 1.2 + RichFaces 3.3.3

We are not able to link the scroll bar of rich:panel to the rich:tree component. The selection or highlighting the node is happening in the rich:tree. But we are unable to link the scroll bar with the highlighted node, so even when the selection is overflowing the div, the scroll bar is not moving accordingly due to which the highlighted node becomes invisible to the user.

If we scroll down to the particular node manually we can see that the node is highlighted.

We have tried the following steps to resolve but the issue hasn't resolve

1. Call a js at every down or up arrow press and move the scroll bar of the main div by a fixed height using 
   container.scrollTop= 16.
2. Pass the highlighted node and scroll into view that node using treeItem.scrollIntoView(true);
   and  container.scrollTop.
3. Tried to find out the highlighted node and then pass it to the js, but found it difficult to access the highlighted node at the front end.

Struggling with this issue for more than 2 days.

How to resolve this issue? Are we cornered?

Appreciate your help in advance.
Ramesh

Code snippet:

```
        <div class="treespaceheight" >
    <rich:panel styleClass="treeStyleClass">

        <rich:tree styleClass="treewidth" id="tree" 
            iconCollapsed="../../images/ImgNodePlus.gif"    
            iconExpanded="../../images/ImgNodeMinus.gif"                    
            reRender="selectedNode" switchType="client"
            ajaxSubmitSelection="true"
            value="#{commoncontroller.quotevo.quotetreeNode}"                           
            ondblclick="setNodeToggle(event);" oncontextmenu="false"   
            adviseNodeOpened="#{commoncontroller.quotevo.adviseNodeOpened}" 
            adviseNodeSelected="#{commoncontroller.quotevo.adviseNodeSelected}" >                                                                       
        </rich:tree>
    </rich:panel>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to get the selected node by css class.
I think you can use

```
jQuery('.rich-tree-node-selected')
```

to get that node!
Or you can just set your own class by edit the tree attr "selectedClass".